# TabLayout изменение иконок

Tags: android-tablayout

Как сделать чтобы иконки в TabLayout менялись в зависимости от того активный таб или нет?

Answer (score 0):

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
        new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabUnselected(tab);
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                super.onTabReselected(tab);
            }
        }
);
```

`onTabSelected` - выполняется при нажатии на неактивную вкладку

`onTabUnselected` - выполняется при переходе на другую вкладку

`onTabReselected` - выполняется при повторном нажатии на вкладку